# What is the alternative for android.app.AlertDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced when using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android

Currently, I'm migrating from SherlockActionBar to AppCompat.

Hence, I move all the code, from `android.app.AlertDialog` to `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`

I realize, in `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, there is no `setInverseBackgroundForced`

May I know what is the alternative for such method?